# Solving 8-Puzzle in C++ with A* results in endless loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, a-star

I'm currently trying to solve the 8-Puzzle with the A* search algorithm, but my program gets stuck in an endless loop.

My main searching loop is:

```
std::vector<Field> Search::AStar(Field &start, Field &goal){
std::cout << "Calculating..." << std::endl;

std::unordered_map<Field, Field> explored;
std::vector<Field> searched;

if (Puzzle::finished(start))
    return MakePath(start, start);

std::priority_queue<Field, std::vector<Field>, std::greater<Field>> frontier;
frontier.push(start);

Field current;
Field child;

size_t i = 0;
while (!frontier.empty())
{
    current = frontier.top();
    frontier.pop();

    if (++i > 500)
    {
        std::cout << "Iteration Error" << std::endl;
        return searched;
    }

    searched.push_back(current);

    for (Direction d : Puzzle::Actions(current))
    {
        child = Puzzle::Action(d, current);

        if (Puzzle::finished(child))
        {
            std::cout << "Found goal!" << std::endl;
            return MakePath(explored[child], start);
        }

        child.CostG = current.CostG + 1; // Make a step

        if (!isIn(child, explored) || child.CostG < explored[child].CostG)
        {
            child.CostH = Puzzle::Heuristic(child, goal); // Calculate Heuristic
            child.CostF = child.CostG + child.CostH; // Calculate final costs

            frontier.push(child);
            explored[child] = child;
            explored[child].setParent(&explored[current]);
        }
    }
}

std::cout << "Error: frontier Empty" << std::endl;

return searched;
}
```

The vector "searched" is just so that I can see what A* does, and I will delete it as soon as the algorithm works.

The CostG stands for the number of steps done until this point, the CostH are the estimated minimum (heuristic) costs to the "goal" and the CostF are those two combined.

The index of the Field::Boxes vector is the number of the field, and every element contains the position.

My Heuristic function looks like this:

```
    inline int Heuristic(Field &goal)
{
    size_t d = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < Boxes.size(); i++)
    {
        d += (std::abs(static_cast<int>(Boxes[i].x) - static_cast<int>(goal.Boxes[i].x))
            + std::abs(static_cast<int>(Boxes[i].y) - static_cast<int>(goal.Boxes[i].y)));
    }

    return d;
}
```

For better readability and stuff, the code also is on [Github](https://github.com/GabsStudios/Algorithms). However, to execute it, you need SFML in your Visual Studio include direction.

Every help is appreciated!

**Edit 1:**
You now no longer need SFML to executed & debug the program! I commited the changes to github, the link is the same.

Comment: Please spend some time learning how to debug a program.  It is just as important is learning the language.

Comment: Reduce the code to a small self-contained sample that readers can try.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I think I debugged the code for like 6 hours. I found some errors, made some things better, but it's still not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that although you remove the `current` node from your frontier, you never added it to the `explored` set, i.e. you never close it. The following code *should* work. My revisions closely follow [Wikipedia's A* Pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

I also recommend you test your algorithm with the trivial heuristic (the one that returns zero for all values) on a simple puzzle to verify that your algorithm is implemented correctly. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38153492/3795219) for a brief explanation of this technique.)

```
while (!frontier.empty())
{
    current = frontier.top();
    frontier.pop();

    if (++i > 500)
    {
        std::cout << "Iteration Error" << std::endl;
        return searched;
    }

    // Check for goal here
    if (Puzzle::finished(current)
    {
        std::cout << "Found goal!" << std::endl;
        return MakePath(explored[current], start);
    }

    explored[current] = current; //close the current node
    searched.push_back(current);

    for (Direction d : Puzzle::Actions(current))
    {
        child = Puzzle::Action(d, current);

        if (isIn(child,explored)) 
        {
            continue; //ignore the neighbor which is already evaluated
        }

        child.CostG = current.CostG + 1; // Make a step

        if (!isIn(child, frontier)) //discovered a new node
        {
            frontier.push(child);
        } 
        else if (child.CostG >= explored[child].CostG)
        {
            continue; //this is not a better path
        {

        //the path is best until now. Record it!
        child.CostH = Puzzle::Heuristic(child, goal); // Calculate Heuristic
        child.CostF = child.CostG + child.CostH; // Calculate final costs

        //frontier.push(child); moved up to earlier point in code
        explored[child] = child;
        explored[child].setParent(&explored[current]);

    }
}
```