# A* Pathfinding in a hexagonal grid

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, path-finding, a-star

Can anyone point me to a simple example that implements [A* path-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) on a **hexagonal** grid (in JS). I have made it working on a square grid, however all my attempts to make it work on a hexagonal grid have failed.

This is how my grid looks like:

[image]

I'm using the same technique to both draw the grid and generate coordinates as seen in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734438/algorithm-to-generate-a-hexagonal-grid-with-coordinate-system).

Here's the grid coords data along with the start, end coords:

```
        [0, 0] , [0, 1],  [0, 2],
    [1, 0],  [1, 1],  [1, 2],  [1, 3],
 [2, 0],  [2, 1],  [2, 2],  [2, 3],  [2, 4],
    [3, 0],  [3, 1], [3, 2],  [3, 3], 
        [4, 0], [4, 1],  [4, 2]


start_point: [0,2]
end_point: [4.0]
```

After updating the manhattan distance calculation to:

```
var dx = pos1[0] - pos0[0];
    var dy = pos1[1] - pos0[1];

    var dist;
    if ( Math.sign(dx) == Math.sign(dy) ){
        dist = Math.abs (dx + dy);
    }else{
        dist = Math.max(Math.abs(dx), Math.abs(dy))
    }

return dist;
```

I get this result:

[image]

and also the way I'm calculating the shortest path:

```js
if (!Array.prototype.remove) {
    Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
        var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
        this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
        return this.push.apply(this, rest);
    };
}

var astar = {
    init: function(grid) {
        for(var x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
            for(var y = 0; y < grid[x].length; y++) {
                grid[x][y].f = 0;
                grid[x][y].g = 0;
                grid[x][y].h = 0;
    //grid[x][y].content = false;
                grid[x][y].visited = false;
                grid[x][y].closed = false;
                grid[x][y].debug = "";
                grid[x][y].parent = null;
    console.log([grid[x][y].coords[0],grid[x][y].coords[1]])
            }
        }
    },
    search: function(grid, start, end, heuristic) {
        this.init(grid);
        heuristic = heuristic || this.manhattan;

        var openList = [];
  
  //// find the start and end points in the grid ////
  start = grid[start.pos[0]][start.pos[1]];
  end =  grid[end.pos[0]][end.pos[1]];
  
  console.log( start, end )
  
        openList.push(start);
  
        while(openList.length > 0) {
   
            // Grab the lowest f(x) to process next
            var lowInd = 0;
            for(var i=0; i<openList.length; i++) {
                if(openList[i].f < openList[lowInd].f) { lowInd = i; }
            }
            var currentNode = openList[lowInd];

            // End case -- result has been found, return the traced path
            if( currentNode == end ) {
                var curr = currentNode;
                var ret = [];
                while(curr.parent) {
                    ret.push(curr);
                    curr = curr.parent;
                }
                return ret.reverse();
            }

            // Normal case -- move currentNode from open to closed, process each of its neighbors
            openList.remove( lowInd );
            currentNode.closed = true;

            var neighbors = this.neighbors(grid, currentNode);
            for(var i=0; i<neighbors.length;i++) {
                var neighbor = neighbors[i];

                if( neighbor.closed || neighbor.content == 2 ) { // not a valid node to process, skip to next neighbor
                    continue;
                }

                // g score is the shortest distance from start to current node, we need to check if
                //   the path we have arrived at this neighbor is the shortest one we have seen yet
                var gScore = currentNode.g + 1; // 1 is the distance from a node to it's neighbor
                var gScoreIsBest = false;

                if(!neighbor.visited) {
                    // This the the first time we have arrived at this node, it must be the best
                    // Also, we need to take the h (heuristic) score since we haven't done so yet
                    gScoreIsBest = true;
                    neighbor.h = heuristic(neighbor.coords, end.coords);
                    neighbor.visited = true;
                    openList.push(neighbor);
                }
                else if(gScore < neighbor.g) {
                    // We have already seen the node, but last time it had a worse g (distance from start)
                    gScoreIsBest = true;
                }

                if(gScoreIsBest) {
                    // Found an optimal (so far) path to this node.  Store info on how we got here and just how good it really is. ////
                    neighbor.parent = currentNode;
                    neighbor.g = gScore;
                    neighbor.f = neighbor.g + neighbor.h;
                    neighbor.debug = "F: " + neighbor.f + "<br />G: " + neighbor.g + "<br />H: " + neighbor.h;
                }
            }
        }

        // No result was found -- empty array signifies failure to find path
        return [];
    },
    manhattan: function(pos0, pos1) { //// heuristics : use manhattan distances  ////
        var dx = pos1[0] - pos0[0];
        var dy = pos1[1] - pos0[1];
  
        return  Math.abs (dx + dy);
    },
    neighbors: function(grid, node) {
        var ret = [];
        var x = node.coords[0];
        var y = node.coords[1];
  
        if(grid[x-1] && grid[x-1][y] ) {
            ret.push(grid[x-1][y]);
        }
        if( grid[x+1] && grid[x+1][y] ) {
            ret.push(grid[x+1][y]);
        }
        if( grid[x][y-1] && grid[x][y-1] ) {
            ret.push(grid[x][y-1]);
        }
        if( grid[x][y+1] && grid[x][y+1] ) {
            ret.push(grid[x][y+1]);
        }
        return ret;
    }
};
```

Tried looking around for some good examples or documents on the internet but couldn't really find anything of use.

Comment: Need some clarification. Do you have a heuristic you're working off of? Do you have an existing hexagonal grid?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734438/algorithm-to-generate-a-hexagonal-grid-with-coordinate-system This is how my grid looks like, except that I turned the whole Java  code this into JS. As you can see the grid is using Axial coordinate system, and this is the heuristic I'm using  to calculate the distance 
`var dx = Math.abs (pos1.x - pos0.x);
        var dy = Math.abs (pos1.y - pos0.y);
        return dx + dy;`

Comment: The alternate coordinate system described in this question may help, as will the question itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084801/manhattan-distance-between-tiles-in-a-hexagonal-grid since Manhattan distance will be a good first heuristic. *edit: it's the same coordinate system, just rotated.

Comment: Questions asking for pointers to examples (and for any links in general) are off-topic on SO. The bounty won't change that. Please post your code, especially the one with the failed attempt, tell us what is not working and what you'd expect. With such a specific question, we could help you.

Comment: I have updated my question with some more details, please let me know in case it's still not clear enough.

Comment: @Alexus: Your manhattan distance implementation works only for rectangular grids, it's invalid on your hexagonal grid - and as such leads to weird results. Use the one from the answer linked by PWhite instead.

Comment: I have updated the distance calculation, but it's still returning some weird results. Also I don't seem to understand that bit about converting the  (x', y) coordinates to (x,y). Does this apply on this case as well?

Answer (score 18):

The problem resides in your `neighbors` method: although a hexagon has six neighbors (6), you only push four (4) onto `ret`. The following figure highlights the issue. The light grey hex represents the current node (i.e. `neighbor`). The green hexagons are added to `ret`, but the red hexagons are not.

[image: IncludedOrNotIncluded]

To fix this, add the following two (2) cases to your `neighbors` method:

```
    if( grid[x+1][y-1] && grid[x+1][y-1] ) {
        ret.push(grid[x][y-1]);
    }
    if( grid[x-1][y+1] && grid[x-1][y+1] ) {
        ret.push(grid[x][y+1]);
    }
```

**Regarding your updated `manhattan` method:** it is correct. The following figure uses colors to show the distance from the current central hex (at [0:0] in red) to every other hex. For example, the orange hex tiles are one (1) move from the red. The yellow are two (2) moves from the red. And so on.

[image: Distance hex map]

You may notice the pattern: If the x- and y-coordinates share the same sign, the distance is equal to the magnitude of the largest coordinate. Otherwise, the distance is the sum of their absolute values. This is exactly the way you've calculated distance in your **updated** `manhattan` method. So you're good there.

**Regarding heuristic search in general:** Here's a simple way to check if a suboptimal solution is the result of a bug in the heuristic implementation or else because of a bug in the algorithm implementation. Just use the heuristic value zero (0) for all values, i.e. use the trivial heuristic. If, while using the trivial heuristic, the path is not optimal, then you know it's not a heuristic problem---it's an algorithm problem.

Comment: Not only a good answer, but also good advice on testing the heuristic.

Comment: Why are the y coordinates - at the top and + on the bottom?

Comment: @JesseMoreland Simple answer: It matched the OP's post. More details: By convention in computer graphics, the top left corner of the screen is labeled (0,0), and the x- and y-coordinates increase as you move toward the bottom right corner of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned by someone here, the way I was generating the grid, and also the coordinates were incorrect.

I have another read through Amit Patel's implementation [guide](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/implementation.html) and I used his way to generate the grid and also the coordinates system including the coord. conversions.

```
generate: function(){
        var n_hex = null; 
        var row = 0, col = 0;
        for (var q = -this.grid_r; q <= this.grid_r; q++) {
            var r1 = Math.max(-this.grid_r, -q - this.grid_r);
            var r2 = Math.min(this.grid_r, -q + this.grid_r);
            col = q + this.grid_r;
            this.hexes[ col ] = [];
            for (var r = r1; r <= r2; r++) {
                row = r - r1;
                n_hex = new Hex( [q, r], [col, row], this.layout );
                this.hexes[ col ][ row ] = n_hex;
            }
        }
    },
```

As I started using the cube coordinates , the only thing I had to change in the a* pathfinding algorithm was the distance calculation:

```
return Math.max(Math.abs(a.x - b.x), Math.abs(a.y - b.y), Math.abs(a.z - b.z))
```

now the path-finding is working on both "pointy" and "flat" layouts :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a solved problem, with much literature to back it up. The best resource I know is on Red Blob Games: https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/.

In brief, the most likely reason is that you chose the wrong coordinate system. Using a Cube coordinate system implementing the A* algorithm is quite simple. See the live demo on the above link.

If you *really* want to use some other system, then convert to and from when needed.

Answer (score 1):

The "classic" path finding algorithm works as follows:

- Initialize all cells with zero.
- Start at the starting point and mark this point with the number 1.
- Loop start with n = 1:
- Take all cells with number n and mark all adjacent cells, which contains a zero, with number (n+1). If any of these adjacent cells is the exit, leave loop. If no adjacent cell with number zero found, there's no path to exit.
- Increment n and goto loop

If exit found then:

- Start loop at exit:
- Search adjacent cell with number n and remember this cell.
- Decrement n and goto loop

All remembered cells builds up the result path (in reverse order).

Cheerz

Hennes

Comment: The astar pathfiinding I'm currently using in my square grid is working perfectly, however it gives me some weird results when using the same pattern on a hexagonal grid (see my updated post above). Also I'm not sure whether to use the [row, col] position in the grid or the axial coordinates to calculate the path

Comment: I tried this algorithm already in rectangular 2D, 3D and triangular (instead of hexagonal) shapes, and it always worked, finding the shortest path.

Comment: I'm sure it works, mine works as well in a square / rectangular grids. But not in a hexagonal. I didn't down-vote your answer , even though it does not solve my problem.

Comment: This is Breadth First Search, and should work in a hex grid (note: the original question was about A\* Search)

Comment: It's the first time, that I used this kind of algorithm. Coded like you wrote it --> it worked --> Thanks 